# mod_rewrite rewrite help needed in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have looked online for a solution here but I am struggling to find the right answer. Hopefully someone can help.

I have the following translation link on a webpage like so, `<a href="/de/about/">Translate</a>` but the actual path was on my server is `/_translations/de/about/`.

Currently, the link goes to a 404 error and of course works if I prepend the url to the actual path.

What would be the rewrite rule for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /_translations/$1/$2 [L]
```